# Meaning of derivatives in Calculus

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm having some trouble in interpreting the derivative of a function equals a constant.

Suppose, for example, that

$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 =1$. This represents a sphere of radius unity. If I take the derivative of both sides of that equation with respect to $x$, I get $2x = 0$, or $x=0$. What does this result means? Is there some geometrical interpretation?

Comment: $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ is not a function. It's an equation. The derivative is defined for functions.

Comment: So I can't take the derivative of both sides of this equation?

Comment: Implicit differentiation of both sides yields... 
$$ 2x+2y\frac{dy}{dx}+2z\frac{dz}{dx} =0 $$

Comment: @WW1, x,y,z are supposed to be independent variables. I forgot to add this in the question, sorry

Comment: they can't be entirely independent if they are constrained by $$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 =1$$

Comment: You could take the derivative of both sides of an equation, but don't expect it to have any kind of sensate interpretation. When you have an **equality** between two **functions**, $f(x) = g(x)$, then it makes sense to take the derivative on both sides, and you'll get a new equality between two new functions.

Comment: You're correct, @WW1. Only two of them can be independent. That was my mistake. Thank you very much!

Comment: @jjagmath, Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

Think of a particle moving in a path on the sphere defined by $\vec r(t) \equiv (x(t), y(t), z(t))$

- Then the equation of the sphere is equivalent to $\vec r \cdot \vec r=1$
- Differentiating both sides (with respect to time) yields the equation
  $$\vec r \cdot \frac{d\vec r}{dt}=0$$

Which admits the interpretation that any particle constrained to move on a sphere centred on the origin always has its velocity vector perpendicular to its position vector.

- To see that this applies to the case of differentiation with respect to $x$ as well as $t$, you have only to consider the paths parameterized by $\vec r(t) = (t, y(t), z(t))$